# Push another view when click on rightCalloutAccessoryView

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios5, storyboard

When I click on the right callout on the PIN, i want to move to a new view controller named `DetailsThemes`, however, when i do so:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailsThemes animated:YES];
}
```

I got this error:

```
Property detailsThemes not found on object of type 'ViewController *'; 
    did you mean to access ivar 'detailsThemes'?
```

Although, `detailsThemes` is an instance of `DetailsThemes` which is a UIViewController class, also, in my class I did invoke the `DetailsThemes` class with `@class DetailsThemes;` on the top of the file like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@class DetailsThemes;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate> 
{
    DetailsThemes * detailsThemes;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

**EDIT:**

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    NSLog(@"calloutAccessoryControlTapped: %@",view.annotation);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailsThemes animated:YES];


}
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {


    static NSString *identifier = @"ManageAnnotations";   

    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    } else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    [annotationView setAnimatesDrop:YES];
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    //annotationView.pinColor = ((ManageAnnotations *)annotation).pinColor;
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
    return annotationView;

}
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? Read twice, it has the explanation. You have to declare @property for detailsThemes or access the ivar directly.

Comment: I did, okay, now i got everything working great, however, when i click on the right info button of the PIN, i got nothing, the details view is not charged.

Comment: Is calloutAccessoryControlTapped actually getting called?  Put an NSLog or breakpoint in it to be sure.

Comment: Hi, i have edited my post, actually, the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped ` gets called, that's why i am a bit confused, i have declared a property for the details class but i got nothing, the details view is not pushed up when i click on the info button of the PIN.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ViewDidLoad` method you have to allocate first your `DetailsThemes` and then use it in your call out. if you still not success then please post code of your callOutAccessoryView